# Why does Mockito throw an "InvalidUseOfMatchersException" at for this code?

Tags: kotlin, mockito, junit5

I am writing a test for a Spring-Boot project written in Kotlin 1.5. This piece of code does fail at test runtime with an `InvalidUseOfMatchersException` and I struggle to figure out why:

```
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
internal class ControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    lateinit var mockMvc: MockMvc

    @MockBean
    lateinit var mockedAuthFilter: AuthFilter

    @BeforeEach
    fun setup() {
        assertNotNull(mockedAuthFilter)
        `when`(
            mockedAuthFilter.shouldProceed(
                any(HttpServletRequest::class.java),
                any(AuthConfig::class.java)
            )
        ).thenReturn(true)
    }
    @Test
    fun `This call should return without an error`() {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/api/entities")).andDo(print()).andExpect(status().isOk)
    }
}
```

All I can find in the web for this error is that you tried an argument matcher on a basic type - but that is not the case here. Have you faced this problem and how did you solve it?

Comment: Is the exception thrown during setup or when running the test method? Including the stack trace may be helpful.

Comment: The error occurs definitely during setup, on line `any(HttpServletRequest::class.java),`

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding the failure comes from a masked nullpointer exception caused by the `shouldProceed` method itself which doesn't allow a call with nulled arguments, which kind of happens internally in Mockito during the setup of the mocked instance after `any()` returns.

The solution was to not use Mockito with Kotlin, but the MockK test utility instead.